# Used tuple unpacking in Python, can't figure out the logical error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, iterable-unpacking

Can't seem to figure out the problem here :

I'm passing a list

```
vote_sort([("TOD",12),("Football",20),("Baseball",19),("Tennis",10)])
```

The output that i'm getting

```
[('Baseball', 19), ('Football', 20), ('TOD', 12), ('Tennis', 10)]
```

Desired Output :

```
[('Football', 20), ('Baseball', 19), ('TOD', 12), ('Tennis', 10)]
```

Thanks For The Help!

```py
def vote_sort(ls):
    firstIndex = -1
    for a, b in ls:
        # EXTRACT THE VOTES = b
        firstIndex += 1
        for index in range(firstIndex+1, len(ls)):
            # COMPARISON,SORT AND SWAP
            if ls[index][1] > b:
                temp = ls[index]
                ls[index] = ls[firstIndex]
                ls[firstIndex] = temp 
    print(ls)

vote_sort([("TOD",12),("Football",20),("Baseball",19),("Tennis",10)])
```

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to get sorted list by the descending numeric value?

Comment: Yes, would be great if you can point out the error for me here.

Comment: Why not use `sorted()` builtin function?

Comment: The tuple unpacking is fine. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask] for advice.

Comment: How do I unpack a tuple from a list and sort it using sorted()

Comment: @DbridgedDev You can do `print( sorted(lst, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True) )` where `lst` is your list.

Comment: Thanks! Would be really helpful if someone can tell me why I'm getting an error with the code that I've posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print(sorted(L, key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True))
```

Output:

```
[('Football', 20), ('Baseball', 19), ('TOD', 12), ('Tennis', 10)]
```

EDIT:

You asked about your code: the major problem is how you treat the outer loop. In the inner loop b changes its position, but you keep comparing with it. For example, at first iteration for both loops position of b is 0, firstIndex is 0 and index is 1. Imagine, you’ve swapped then, at the next iteration for the inner loop you get that b is at position 1, firstIndex still 0, index is 2. Then you will compare elements 1 and 2, but swapping elements 0 and 2.
You should in the outer loop iterate not by value, but by index.
If you still like writing your own sort function I'd suggest something like this taking your code as base:

```
def vote_sort(ls):
    for i in range(len(ls)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(ls)):
            if ls[i][1] > ls[j][1]:
                tmp = ls[i]
                ls[i] = ls[j]
                ls[j] = tmp

    print(ls[::-1])
```

Comment: Thanks! Would be great if you can point out the error in my code.